# OS X Yosemite 10.10.3 で外付けHDDが認識されるが、Finderのサイドバーに表示されない

Tags: macos

本日システムドライブをフォーマットしてMacOS X Yosemiteの初期化を行いました。
すると、なぜか普段使っていた外付けHDD（Aという名前）がFinderに表示されず、無理やり移動して「よく使う項目」にドライブを配置したのですがクリックして移動することができません。

Bドライブはタイムカプセルのドライブになっていて正常にアクセスすることができます。

ディスクユーティリティを確認してみるとマウントはしっかりされているようです。

毎回この手順を踏まないとドライブに移動できません。
挙動としては、ドライブがドット（.）から始まる名前の隠しファイルのような挙動をしているようにも見えます。

スクリーンショットではXtraFinderを利用したものになっていますが、XtraFinderをアンインストールしてみても結果は同じでした。

いったい何が原因なのでしょうか。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

質問内容がスタックオーバーフローに不適切だと自分で判断したためこの質問はクローズさせていただきます。